# (sysmalloc: Assertion) using several MALLOCS to populate a triple pointer in the HEAP

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, malloc

I'm new in programming and as an assign I was told to do a mini Bash. I decided to do a parser that in case of no lexical errors in the command to analyze, would populate a char*** (as far as I understand it would be a matrix of strings).

The problem I have is that at a certain point I get a sysmalloc assertion that I don't understand. My code is very bad (until now I never do a Free), but I think it should at least run and using valgrind tell me that I've got a memory leak.

I'm beginning to learn how to use correctly C pointers so please be nice. If someone understands which is the problem(it must be in the parser function), I would really appreciate them explaining it to me. Here is the code(if someone needs to see more of the code please tell me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>                    
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char*** parser(char*);
size_t token_counter(const char const *, char);
bool double_occurrence(char*, char, size_t);
bool line_semantic_correctness(char*);
bool arg_semantic_correctness(char*, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char a[]={"cat /etc/passwd | grep -i \"boo\" | grep bash suca blyat andrea e frocio | a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z | <file1 <file2 suca"};
    char*** to_parse = parser(a);
    int cmd_index = 0;

    if(to_parse != NULL){
        while(to_parse[cmd_index] != NULL){
            int arg_index = 0;
            printf("cmd %d\n", cmd_index);
            while(to_parse[cmd_index][arg_index] != NULL){
                printf("%s\n", to_parse[cmd_index][arg_index]);
                ++arg_index;
            }
            ++cmd_index;
        }
    }
}

char*** parser(char* line){
    if(!line_semantic_correctness(line))
        return NULL;

    char*** mtrx = NULL;

    size_t cmds_num = token_counter(line, '|');         //counts how many non '|' tokens are present in the command
    size_t rowsto_alloc = cmds_num+1;
    if((mtrx=malloc(rowsto_alloc*sizeof(char**))) == NULL){        
        perror("");
        return NULL;
    }
    mtrx[cmds_num]=NULL;
    char* cmd;
    char* cmd_context;
    int cmd_index = 0;
    for(cmd=strtok_r(line, "|", &cmd_context); cmd!=NULL; 
        cmd=strtok_r(NULL, "|", &cmd_context)){
        size_t args_num = token_counter(cmd, ' ');                                                  
        //counts how many non ' ' tokens are present in the command
        size_t colsto_alloc = args_num+1;                                                                      
        if((mtrx[cmd_index]=malloc(colsto_alloc*sizeof(char*))) == NULL){
            perror("");
            //free?
            return NULL;
        }
        mtrx[cmd_index][cmds_num] = NULL;
        char** toredirect = NULL;
        size_t toredirect_sz = 1;
        char* arg;
        char* arg_context;
        int arg_index = 0;
        for(arg=strtok_r(cmd, " ", &arg_context); arg!=NULL; arg=strtok_r(NULL, " ", &arg_context)){
            if(!arg_semantic_correctness(arg, arg_index)){                                                      //analyzes a particular command and returns false when it's not a valid
                perror("");
                //MEGA FREE: da implementare
                return NULL;
            }
            size_t arg_sz = strlen(arg) + 1;
            //if in a command I have redirections written like "<file1" or ">file2" I save them in a double pointer and after analyzing the particular command I push them at the end 
            //of the corresponding row in my triple pointer
            if((arg[0] == '<' ) || (arg[0] == '>' )){
                size_t torealloc = toredirect_sz + 1;
                if((toredirect=realloc(toredirect, torealloc*sizeof(char*))) == NULL){
                    perror("");
                    //free da fare
                    return NULL;
                }
                toredirect[toredirect_sz] = NULL;

                if((toredirect[toredirect_sz-1] = malloc(arg_sz)) == NULL){
                    perror("");
                    //free da fare
                    return NULL;                                        
                }
                strncpy(toredirect[toredirect_sz-1], arg, arg_sz);
                ++toredirect_sz;
            }
            //in the case the particular argument of a command is not a redirection, I put it directly on the triple pointer
            else{
                //AFTER THIS ALLOCATION I GET THE SYSMALLOC ASSERTION (when trying to add the second command to the triple pointer)
                if((mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index] = malloc(arg_sz)) == NULL){
                    perror("");
                    //mega free!!!
                    return NULL;
                }
                strncpy(mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index], arg, arg_sz);
                ++arg_index;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; arg_index+i < args_num; ++i){
            size_t tocopy_sz = strlen(toredirect[i]) + 1;
            if((mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index+i] = malloc(tocopy_sz*sizeof(char))) == NULL){
                perror("");
                //mega free!!!
                return NULL;
            }
            strncpy(mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index+i], toredirect[i], tocopy_sz);
        }
        //FREE DI REDIRECTIONS !!!!!!!
        ++cmd_index;
    }
    return mtrx;
 }

size_t token_counter(const char const * str, char delim){
    size_t tok_num = 0;
    size_t str_sz = strlen(str);
    bool increment = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < str_sz; ++i){
        if(str[i] == delim){
            increment = true;
            continue;
        }
        else if(increment == true){
            ++tok_num;
            increment = false;
        }
    }
    return tok_num;
}

bool double_occurrence(char* str, char occ, size_t line_sz){
    for(int i = 0; i < (line_sz - 1); ++i){
        if((str[i] == occ) && (str[i+1] == occ))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool line_semantic_correctness(char* line){
    if(line == NULL){
        perror("");
        return false;
    }
    if(line[0] == '\0'){
        perror("");
        return false;
    }

    size_t line_size = strlen(line);

    if(double_occurrence(line, '|', line_size)){
        perror("");
        return false;
    }

    if((line[0] == '|') || (line[line_size - 1] == '|')){
        perror("");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// se restituisce false, RICORDIAMOCI di fare la mega FREE
bool arg_semantic_correctness(char* arg, int arg_index){
    switch(arg_index){
        case 0:
            if(arg[0] == '\0'){
                perror("");
                return false;
            }
        default:
            //controllo redirezioni senza file attaccati 

            if(strlen(arg) == 1){
                if((arg[0] == '<') || (arg[0] == '>')){
                    perror("");
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please give us a minimal example. The code, as you provided it, is not compilable,

Comment: I just added the code to be able to compile. Take in consideration that assigning the string "cat /etc/passwd | grep -i \"boo\" | grep bash suca blyat andrea e frocio | a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z" to the array in the main will let you execute without errors. Instead, the one in the code gets sysmalloc assertion. The error happens in the parser function.

Answer (score 0):

```
99                      if((mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index] = malloc(arg_sz)) == NULL){
(gdb) p cmd_index 
$10 = 0
(gdb) p arg_index
$11 = 1
(gdb) n
104                     strncpy(mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index], arg, arg_sz);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, parser (line=0x7fffffffdfc0 "cat") at main.c:99
99                      if((mtrx[cmd_index][arg_index] = malloc(arg_sz)) == NULL){
(gdb) p cmd_index 
$12 = 1
(gdb) p arg_index
$13 = 0
(gdb) p arg_sz
$14 = 5
(gdb) n
```

maybe the erro is you can not use char*** with array, because system doesn't know what size in array[] or array[][] or array[][][]

just like int** in array[12] and array[3][4] is different

you need init this char*** with char[][][]

and

```
char a[]={"cat /etc/passwd | grep -i \"boo\" | grep bash andrea e | a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z | <file1 <file2 suca"};
```

this in char* argv not char array, it is string array, just like

```
argv[0] = ".\a.out"
argv[1] = "cat"
argv[2] = "/etc/passwd"
......
```